# Can I change the timeout value on a setTimer object by setting its _idleTimeout member?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const st = new Date();

const timer = setTimeout(() => console.log(new Date() - st), 1000);
timer._idelTimout = 2000;

console.log(timer);
```

**Output**:

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 53,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  _idelTimout: 2000,
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 }
1006
```

Is there anyway that I can make the timer delay more using this **Timer** Object directly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use screenshots to show us code. You are much more likely to get answers if you put the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change the timeout value on a setTimer object by setting its _idleTimeout member?

**No**. Do not do this. Use `clearTimeout()`, then `setTimeout()` to create a new timeout with your newly desired duration.

Members of objects with names starting with `_` underscores, like `_idleTimeout`, are considered private for the implementer of the object.  The implementer of the timeout object, therefore, is telling you not to mess around with the `_idleTimeout` member.

If you change a private member, or even make your own code depend on its value or even its presence, the results are *unpredictable.* The implementer is free to change the use of such members at any time without notice.  And, the implementation may be different in various versions of various browsers.

You really really do not want to introduce unpredictability in code that affects the Javascript event loop. Seriously.